# Using w3-include-html breaks some tags and JS scripts stop working

Tags: javascript, html, apache

I just got my bachelor's degree in Computer Science and I was wanting to make a portfolio website to pair with my resume. I first was just using a basic static HTML. Then eventually I thought to myself there has to be a better way to do this when I have multiple pages with the exact same content, that being a header and a footer. I found out about w3-include-html and there we go I have dynamic webpages and I no longer have to update the same HTML on multiple pages. Except I have realized that something is wrong. It seems meta, link tags, and potentially other tags as well, but also JS scripts inside included HTML files do not work. I have no experience with website building really other than a very small amount of HTML coding from high school. I thought I would be able to push my way through from all my other CS experience, but I just cannot figure out this bug. From what I have seen other people can use JS scripts inside an included HTML file, so I am not sure what is wrong.

The facts:

- The tab icon, does not work if it is inside **header.html**. It only works if I put it inside **index.html**.
- The website description is just like the tab icon does not work in **footer.html** only inside **header.html**.
- In both OperaGX, Chrome, and Edge if I inspect the webpage the header and the footer are inside the body tag for some reason unlike what the **index.html** has. Which I believe may be the culprit, but I cannot figure out how to fix this.
  [image: Chrome Inspect]
- **footer.html** contains a very basic JavaScript script to print the current year for the copywrite notice, yet it is not visible unless I put that code directly inside **index.html** instead.
- I am using Apache2 to host the website inside a docker container, it is the httpd:2-alpine docker image.
- I am using NginxProxyManager as a reverse proxy which gives the website a TLS certificate for HTTPS, it is the jlesage/nginx-proxy-manager docker image.
- I am in fact fully refreshing the page after update by using CONTROL + F5 and sometimes even manually deleting cached data just in case. So I am in fact seeing new changes.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <!-- <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/icons/terminal16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/icons/terminal48x48.png" sizes="48x48"> -->
    <div w3-include-html="modules/header.html"></div>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- ... -->
</body>

<footer>
    <div w3-include-html="modules/footer.html"></div>
    <!-- <div class="container">
        <small>Matthew Green &copy; 2022 -
            <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script>
        </small>
    </div> -->
</footer>

<script src="scripts/include_html.js"></script>
<script>includeHTML();</script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.13.1/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script async defer src="https://buttons.github.io/buttons.js"></script>
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        document.querySelectorAll("pre code").forEach(block => {
            window.hljs.highlightBlock(block);
        });
    });
</script>

</html>
```

**header.html**

```
<!-- Meta Data -->
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/icons/terminal16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/icons/terminal48x48.png" sizes="48x48">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff" />
<title>Matthew Green's Showcase</title>
<meta name="description"
    content="Hi, I am Matthew Green and this is a showcase of all my work experience, skills, and projects." />



<!-- Styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/terminal.css@0.7.2/dist/terminal.min.css" />
<style>
    .components-grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-column-gap: 1.4em;
        grid-template-columns: auto;
        grid-template-rows: auto;
    }

    .image-grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: auto;
        display: grid;
        grid-gap: 1em;
        grid-template-rows: auto;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit,
                minmax(calc(var(--page-width) / 12), 1fr));
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 70em) {
        .components-grid {
            grid-template-columns: 3fr 9fr;
        }
    }
</style>

<style>
    :root {
        --global-font-size: 15px;
        --global-line-height: 1.4em;
        --global-space: 10px;
        --font-stack: Menlo, Monaco, Lucida Console, Liberation Mono,
            DejaVu Sans Mono, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Courier New, monospace,
            serif;
        --mono-font-stack: Menlo, Monaco, Lucida Console, Liberation Mono,
            DejaVu Sans Mono, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Courier New, monospace,
            serif;
        --background-color: #222225;
        --page-width: 60em;
        --font-color: #e8e9ed;
        --invert-font-color: #222225;
        --secondary-color: #a3abba;
        --tertiary-color: #a3abba;
        --primary-color: #62c4ff;
        --error-color: #ff3c74;
        --progress-bar-background: #3f3f44;
        --progress-bar-fill: #62c4ff;
        --code-bg-color: #3f3f44;
        --input-style: solid;
        --display-h1-decoration: none;
    }
</style>



<!-- Navigation Bar -->
<div class="container">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

**footer.html**

```
<p>
    <small>Matthew Green &copy; 2022-
        <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script>
    </small>
</p>
```

**scripts/include_html.js**

```
function includeHTML() {
    var z, i, elmnt, file, xhttp;
    /* Loop through a collection of all HTML elements: */
    z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
        elmnt = z[i];
        /*search for elements with a certain atrribute:*/
        file = elmnt.getAttribute("w3-include-html");
        if (file) {
            /* Make an HTTP request using the attribute value as the file name: */
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4) {
                    if (this.status == 200) { elmnt.innerHTML = this.responseText; }
                    if (this.status == 404) { elmnt.innerHTML = "Page not found."; }
                    /* Remove the attribute, and call this function once more: */
                    elmnt.removeAttribute("w3-include-html");
                    includeHTML();
                }
            }
            xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
            xhttp.send();
            /* Exit the function: */
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried removing and adding different tags on all the different HTML files, such as the head tag, no dice. I thought maybe it was just OperaGX moving my included HTML code to the body but after checking both Chrome and Edge that is not the case. I have tried using the w3-include-html by having the source script directly from the w3 website, didn't change anything. I have moved the includeHTML() call inside the head tag, it didnt change anything as well.

If anyone has any ideas on what is wrong I would appreciate some help sooooooo much.

Comment: Note that [W3Schools](//www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp) has _nothing to do_ with the [W3C](//www.w3.org), other than a vaguely similar name tricking novices into thinking otherwise. Learning from W3Schools is _not_ recommended. The modern approach is to use [`<template>`: The Content Template element](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template).

Comment: Instead of complicating things with some w3schools nonsense, why not just use a proper server side language, like PHP, and include your includes the easier way? As Sebastian noted, no one considers w3schools a reliable source

Answer (score 0):

Okay so a template tag did not seem to be what I needed. Maybe I could have gotten it to work, but at a quick glance seem to be not what I was asking for. Maybe that comment will help someone else who reads this later. But thanks for the idea Sebastian.

For me I went with PHP like j08691 recommended. I ended up switching docker containers from httpd:2-alpine to chvb/docker-apache-php which is on the Apps page for my OS Unraid. It just seemed easier than trying to get PHP working on my apache2 configuration. Although once I did that I had some problems with document access, but I was able to fix that pretty quickly I just had to add a  section to the VirtualHost config and grant access to everything.

I also had to update my index.html to index.php to get the php include to work.

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <?php require 'modules/header.php'; ?>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- ... -->
</body>

<footer>
    <?php require 'modules/footer.php'; ?>
</footer>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.13.1/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script async defer src="https://buttons.github.io/buttons.js"></script>
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        document.querySelectorAll("pre code").forEach(block => {
            window.hljs.highlightBlock(block);
        });
    });
</script>

</html>
```

**footer.php**

```
<?php
echo "
<div class=\"container\">
<small>
    Copyright &copy; 2022-" . date("Y") . " Matthew Green
</small>
</div>
";
```

Then I had an issue with not being able to access my icons. I was just getting an error 403 and error 404 on the icon directory and the icons themselves. However, I noticed that my local IP address they worked fine. Went back to my VirtualHost config and realized I had a placeholder ServerName and ServerAlias. I just completely removed these as my NginxProxyManager handles that stuff already with a reverse proxy as well as the TLS certificate. I also changed the permissions for the files in my www directory as I think this might have been an issue as well with the errors.

A tip for anyone reading:
I swapped from an icon directory and using link tags to just going to https://favicon.io and inputting an .SVG file, which I got from https://fonts.google.com/icons and taking the results and putting them directly into the root www directory. BTW Google Fonts is completely free for all uses including commercial use.

Now the header meta data tags are actually in the header section when inspecting now. I can see the tab icon on all browsers. Also I got the footer correctly displaying the current year.

Cheers to both j08691 and Sebastian for there input.